# raise validation error if there is two president for the same club?

Tags: django, validation, django-models

in my model, I don't want two presidents for the same club. I have 6 clubs so I will have 6 presidents too no more. I'm new to validation I tried to use the clean method but the error won't get raised.

my model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    STUDENT = 1
    INSTRUCTOR = 2
    ADMIN = 3
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (STUDENT, 'student'),
        (INSTRUCTOR, 'instructor'),
        (ADMIN, 'admin'),
    )
    club_name = (
        (0, 'ISOM'),
        (1, 'Accounting'),
        (2, 'PA'),
        (3, 'Finance'),
        (4, 'Management & Marketing'),
        (5, 'Economics'),
    )
    is_president = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    club_name = models.IntegerField(choices=club_name, default=0, verbose_name='Club/Department')
    roles = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
```

the validation I used:

```
def clean(self):
          club = MyUser.objects.all()
          president = MyUser.objects.all()
          try:
            club.objects.get(club_name__iexact=club_name)
            president.objects.get(is_president__iexact=is_president)

          except club.DoesNotExist:
            return club_name, is_president
          raise ValidationError(_("A president for this club already existed."))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest separating out Club as its own model. Its cleaner and would allow you to add more clubs in the future.

```
class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    president = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

For Club membership, you can have a intermediary model:

```
class ClubMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer ... don't try and fix this with code when it's the DB modelling that is wrong!

Comment: thank you for your advice but I can't do that since the clubs are fixed and it's required to choose a club while creating a user.. if I added the club name to my club model then it won't be possible to use signals to auto-create a club president when creating a user that he/she a president.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        club_nam = cleaned_data.get('club_nam')
        
        if MyUser.objects.filter(club_name=club_name, is_president=True).exists():
            raise ValidationError(_("A president for this club already existed."))
```

Comment: did not work and gave me this error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Share entire code views and forms, and think about @TaipanRex answer

Comment: thank you Reza your answer helped me find the solution

Answer (score 0):

> This is the solution that I came up with and worked for me ( inspired by @Reza answer's):

---

```
def clean(self):
   if MyUser.objects.filter(club_name = self.club_name, is_president = True).exists():

      raise ValidationError(_("A president for this club already existed."))
```